# How to setup all GPIO Pin to low during startup in Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspbian, boot

I am facing a problem in Raspberry Pi Robot.

Whenever I reboot the Raspberry Pi, some of the pins are by default configured as `HIGH`. Because of this, Raspberry Pi Robot fails to function correctly during the startup/shutdown sequence.

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer is you can't.

All the GPIO pins start as **inputs** see https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/38059/8697 and also https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/59216/8697

You need to design your interfacing circuitry properly (maybe less beeer), e.g. with appropriate pullups or pulldowns. NOTE the I²C pins have low onboard pullups.